# active admin edit form not pre-populating belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Im using Rails 4 and I have a form within active admin that does not pre-populate or load relationship data into the edit form. If I dont define a form then the default that is loaded by active admin does, but it is shows the object and not the object.name for example so I have set out to edit it.

Here is what I have

```
form do |c|
  c.semantic_errors *c.object.errors.keys
  c.inputs "Event" do
    c.input :title
    c.input :date, :as => :datetime_picker, :local => true 
    c.input :description
  end
  c.inputs "Training Request" do
    c.inputs :for => [:training_request, c.object.training_request || c.object.build_training_request] do |w|
      list_of_training_requests = TrainingRequest.fulfilled.collect {|t| t.host.name }
      w.input :id, as: :select, :collection => list_of_training_requests
    end
  end
  c.inputs "Trainer" do
    c.inputs :for => [:trainer, c.object.trainer || c.object.build_trainer] do |x|
      list_of_trainers = Trainer.qualified.collect {|t| t.name }
      x.input :id, as: :select, :collection => list_of_trainers
    end
  end
  c.actions
end
```

The form loads without any errors and does list data just not what is set the in the database e.g.

[image]

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only problem with the original forms is that it just displays the object instead of name you could overwrite `to_s` in your models. For example:

```
class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Then when you call an instance of `Trainer` it should display the name property.

Comment: thats perfect. I had no idea that would work. Thank you.